# CONDITIONAL FORMATTING for First SIX characters, ALL duplicates Highlight

Tags: worksheet-function, formatting, characters

How do I use CONDITIONAL FORMATTING for the First SIX characters ?  I want ANY and ALL duplicates of the First SIX Characters highlighted.

I need a formula but cannot figure out what formula to use.

This is from my C column

```
UN1377
UN1416999
UN1415
UN1416
UN1424
UN1416 (cont'd)
UN1417
UN1422
UN1365
UN1418
UN1419
UN1423
UN1409
UN1419 (cont'd)
UN1420
```

In this list UN1416999, UN1416 , UN1416 (cont'd) , UN1419 , and UN1419 (cont'd) . Should all show as duplicates because the first six characters for the UN1416 list and the UN1419 list have duplication of the First SIX characters.

I tried using formula "=COUNTIF(Len(C:C,6),Len($C2,6))>1"

BUT this is not correct formula for my C column.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($C$1:$C$15,6)=LEFT(C1,6)))>1
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaaah !!!   That is the formula !!!

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer, so others can see the question is solved.